# Can i use the document object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For an example if we made a App component and we needed to create an element each time a button was clicked:

```
function App() {
  const handleClick = () => {
    // Code here
  }

  return (
    <div id="app">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click here</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is it ok if i used `document.createElement("div")` and `document.getElementById("app").append()` in that case?

```
function App() {
  const handleClick = () => {
    let div = document.createElement("div")

    div.innerHTML = "Hi!"

    document.getElementById("app").append(div)
  }

  return (
    <div id="app">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click here</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: React uses vdom and synthetic events. So most of the time you should stay away from interacting with the Dom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Can you?

You *can*, **but this goes against the idea of React** in the first place and is advised against. Updating the DOM this way can cost you performance and even introduce bugs in your code.

The point of React is to handle updating the DOM in a performant way that is cross-browser compatible. In fact, behind the scenes, React is going to create the `<div>` element and place it in the DOM, but it is going to do so in a less costly and better-managed way by using a virtual representation of the DOM and everything in it. This is not as expensive as directly building, destroying and rebuilding elements on the page, because, for one, not everything on the page needs to be changed each time a user interaction that changes something of the page happens. React will *react* to parts of the page that have changed and keep parts that have not changed improving the performance on your web app. (See
[Reactive Updates](https://reactjs.org/blog/2013/06/05/why-react.html#reactive-updates-are-dead-simple)), This is one of the reasons the React library was built.

React keeps its own internal registry of elements it renders on the page, in the virtual DOM. It updates and tracks them all through their lifecycle on the page. Because of this, it knows which elements to replace, keep or tear down during user interaction. So creating an element by using the `document` object directly circumvents the creation (and registration) of a representation of the element in the virtual DOM making React unaware of the element - leaving the lifecycle handling of the element to the browser.

### The React way

Because of the above, anything that has to do with the UI; including rendering, updating and destroying is best left to React.

The way to build (thanks to JSX and this is an improvement to @yanir's answer) your element is by simply writing out the element where you need it (or storing it in a variable first and using embedded JSX). The `innerHTML` attribute can be an [embedded expression](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx) that is computed in the `div` element. Don't worry, this operation won't cost as much as using the `document` object to create elements directly. We'll just need a form of state to track how many times the user has clicked and create a plain JavaScript object then use the `map()` method to create as many `<div>`s as needed.

```
function App() { 
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = () => {
      let obj = { value: "Hi!" };
      setItems([...items, obj]);
  };

  return (
    <div id="app">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click here</button> 

      {items.map((item, index) => {
        return <div key={index}>{item.value}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you need to interact with the DOM directly, through the `document` object for example, as @Kaushik suggested, you can track the element through the use of hooks like `useRef()`, to get a reference to the object, `useId()` for unique stable Ids across server and client, `useLayoutEffect()` to hook into the browser after DOM updates but before it paints and so on. That being said, there are some APIs and attributes that you may need to access from the `document` object like **events**, `title`, `URL`, and several other attributes. In as much, as these do not mutate the UI, you can use these when needed, while the UI operations are left to React to handle.

Comment: I don't even understand the spread operator -_-

Comment: The array spread operator; `[...arr]` is used to make a copy of an array obj with a different memory reference. Just assigning the `items` state array to a new variable will keep the same reference in memory as the initial array so a change in one will occur in the other. I used the array spread operator because it is bad to change the state directly in React. See why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40309023/11838606 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/37760774/11838606.

Comment: I also used the spread operator because it provides a convenient way for adding a new item to the array without having to first assign to a new array variable and call `.push()` on it. This article can help get you up to speed on the spread operator: https://medium.com/js-dojo/a-beginners-guide-to-using-the-spread-operator-in-javascript-3efd72c18879.

Comment: Based on you're answer about the document object, in that case React is a framework.

Comment: Strictly speaking, React is a library but the `document` object can be accessed from it as well as other libraries and frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

It's fine to use the `document` object for *certain, limited* things in React code,¹ but not in this case. That's not how you'd add an element to your `#app` `div`. Instead, you'd use [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) for it. When switching to an MVC/MVVM/whatever tool like React, you need to stop thinking in terms of modifying the DOM and start thinking in terms of component states.

In your case, for instance, you'd either want a boolean state member telling you whether to render that `Hi!` `div`, or perhaps an array state member of messages you might display.

Here's an example of the former:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
    // The state information
    const [showHi, setShowHi] = useState(false);
    
    const handleClick = () => {
        // Set the state to true on button click
        setShowHi(true);
    };
    
    return <div>
        {/* Check the state and conditionally render */}
        {showHi && <div>Hi!</div>}
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Click here</button>
    </div>;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

I suggest working through the [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) on the React website for a solid introduction to React.

---

¹ A comment asked for examples of what's okay. A non-definitive list:

- Mounting your React root or portal. (Of course. :-) )
- If you need the current scroll offset in an effect or layout effect (`document.documentElement.scrollTop`).
- If you need to look up and possibly manipulate elements that are outside the React tree(s) and can't or shouldn't be brought within the React tree(s) your code is managing. Usually this is when you're incrementally adding React to a codebase that otherwise does DOM manipulation directly (via the DOM itself, or a library like jQuery).

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

When you say «It's fine to use the `document` object **for certain things** in React code», can you give an example of that?

Comment: @floverdevel - I added a couple of examples (and softened that statement, it was overblown). :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you **can**. But the React way to do this is to keep track of this in state. You can keep count of the number of divs you want to render, and update that. State update will trigger a rerender, and your view will be updated.

Below I am using a state variable `count` and initializing an Array using the [`Array()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) constructor of size equal to count.

```
function App() {
  const [count,setCount] = 0;
  const handleClick = () => {
    setCount(count => count+1);
  }

  return (
    <div id="app">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click here</button>
      {Array(count).map((x) => <div>{/**YOUR DIV CONTENT **/}<div>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access the DOM element, the recommended approach is to use the [`useRef`, `useImperativeHandle`, `useLayoutEffect`, or `useid` hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html), as these allow React to be aware of when you are using the DOM elements, and allows for future React updates to not break your existing behavior. In your example though, I would argue that you ***do not*** need access to the DOM element, and that you should instead can let React handle the rendering of the element via declarative JSX.

Answer (score 0):

You don't you `document.getElementById` in reactjs

All point of react is to use jsx (dynamic HTML)

What you can to it's to create an array that you append item to this array each click and use map to render the new item each time :

```
        function App() {
        const [items,setItems] = useState([])
          const handleClick = () => {
            // Code here
    setItems(prev => {
    let arr = []
    //change obj each time to your need.
    let obj = {label : "test" , value : "test"}
    arr.push(obj)
    setItems(arr)
    })
          }
        
          return (
            <div id="app">
              <button onClick={handleClick}>Click here</button>
        {items.map((item,index) =>{
        return <p key={index}>{item.label}</p>
        })
            </div>
          )
        }
```

Comment: In this example, `items` will always contain one item due to how you're updating `items`